# Show USB permission dialog over Android Kiosk application?

Tags: android, android-permissions, kiosk-mode, mtp, android-usb

So I have an application that is pinned to the device with startLockTask command and it has several restrictions so the user cannot escape from the application or change settings of the device.

However, the user should be able to transfer files from the device to a computer via USB, but when the device is connected to a "new" PC, the USB permission dialog: [Allow access to device data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6A2l.png) is not shown because of the LockTask mode.

Is there any way to open that dialog in front of my application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Faced the same problem today,

in my case I solved it by adding `com.android.systemui` package, while adding my whitelist application's in `setLockTaskPackages` DPM's method.

After this I can see the dialogue which was blocking up in `LockTask` mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was not exactly the command that worked but it pushed me to right direction. By adding `com.android.systemui` package I could see the debugging dialog but by adding `com.samsung.android.MtpApplication` I was finally able to see the 'Allow access to device data' dialog. So with Samsung phones this solves the problem and so far it's all I need.

Comment: It works for me. I tried both Asus and Lenovo tablets.

Comment: White-listing `com.android.systemui` did the trick on a Winmate M700D.